# Check if element is a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I check if `$(this)` is a `div`, `ul` or `blockquote`?

For example:

```
if ($(this) is a div) {
  alert('its a div!');
} else {
  alert('its not a div! some other stuff');
}
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
if(this.tagName == 'DIV') {
    alert("It's a div!");
} else {
    alert("It's not a div! [some other stuff]");
}
```

Comment: did you know that `$(this).get(0)` is equivalent to `this` but without the overhead?

Comment: @Bjorn Right, and neither is `this`. `$(this).get(0)` takes `this` (a normal JS DOM node), converts it to a jQuery object, runs `.get(0)`, which selects the first regular DOM node within the jQuery object... that is, takes you back to where you started. `this.tagName = $(this)[0].tagName = $(this).get(0).tagName`.

Comment: @Bryan, it's appalling how people think in jQuery and not anymore in Javascript

Comment: @Bjorn: Of course this does not work. In your example, you pass a string (selector), but in the answer, `this` is already a DOM element. Just try `this === $(this).get(0)`.

Comment: Tripple equal is more correct when you know the type :)

Comment: Worth reminding to use .toLowerCase(), in case javascript decides to randomly return upper case names, even if the names are lower case in the html.

Comment: @Mic and so are you, jQuery is JavaScript. You just seem to have a better understanding what `this` means and `$` stands for ;)

Comment: @dbf, have a look at the edit history of the answer, and you will understand my...wow... already 6 years old comment =D

Comment: @Mic Yes! SO App needs debugging and in need of proof that questions are showing up in wrong places or shouldn't show up at all. Even after 10 years, the comment is still valid, unless jqueryscript is given its own compiler, which I hope, sincerely, is very unlikely .. cheers anyway ;)

Answer (score 48):

Solutions without jQuery are already posted, so I'll post solution using jQuery

```
$(this).is("div,ul,blockquote")
```

Answer (score 22):

To check if this element is DIV

```
if (this instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
   alert('this is a div');
}
```

Same for `HTMLUListElement` for UL,
`HTMLQuoteElement` for blockquote

Comment: Good way for TypeScript!

Comment: Beware using this if you have iframes and such. Each window has its own classes so this would return false even if the element is DIV, but from different window.

Answer (score 21):

Without jQuery you can say `this.tagName === 'DIV'`

Keep in mind that the 'N' in `tagName` is uppercase.

Or, with more tags:

`/DIV|UL|BLOCKQUOTE/.test(this.tagName)`

Answer (score 6):

Old question but since none of the answers mentions this, a modern alternative, without jquery, could be just using a CSS selector and  [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

`element.matches('div, ul, blockquote');`

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
if(this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div"){
    //it's a div
} else {
    //it's not a div
}
```

edit: while I was writing, a lot of answers were given, sorry for doublure

Comment: Nope. `$(this).tagName` is just plain wrong. You mean `$(this).attr('tagName')`

Answer (score 3):

Going through jQuery you can use [`$(this).is('div')`](http://api.jquery.com/is):

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Some of these solutions are going a bit overboard. All you need is `tagName` from regular old JavaScript. You don't really get any benefit from re-wrapping the whole thing in jQuery again, and especially running some of the more powerful functions in the library to check the tag name. If you want to test it on this page, here's an example.

```
$("body > *").each(function() {
  if (this.tagName === "DIV") {
    alert("Yeah, this is a div");
  } else {
    alert("Bummer, this isn't");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let myElement =document.getElementById("myElementId");

if(myElement.tagName =="DIV"){

  alert("is a div");

}else{

  alert("is not a div");

}
/*What ever you may need to know the type write it in capitalised letters "OPTIO" ,"PARAGRAPH", "SPAN" AND whatever */
```

Comment: exactly, CAPITALS

Answer (score 1):

I'm enhancing the answer of Andreq Frenkel, just wanted to add some and it became too lengthy so gone here...

Thinking about CustomElements extending the existing ones and still being able to check if an element is, say, `input`, makes me think that `instanceof` is the best solution for this problem.

One should be aware though, that `instanceof` uses referential equality, so `HTMLDivElement` of a parent window will not be the same as the one of its `iframe` (or shadow DOM's etc).

To handle that case, one should use checked element's own window's classes, something like:

`element instanceof element.ownerDocument.defaultView.HTMLDivElement`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [tagName](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-104682815)